# GPS data not returned in some instances by exif_read_data (PHP 7.3.2, Ubuntu 16\.04)

Tags: php, exif

I have placed an image [here](https://web.lovelady.com/stackoverflow-73557696/DJI_0377.JPG) for which "exif_read_data($name, null, true)" does not return GPS data, and another [here](https://web.lovelady.com/stackoverflow-73557696/DJI_0376.JPG) for which it does return GPS data.  I do not see the difference that causes exif_read_data to miss the GPS data on the first file.  When I inspect these images using other tools, the GPS data is clearly in each file.

What might make this script miss GPS data for one but not for the other?

```
<?php

$filesArray = glob('D*') ;
foreach ($filesArray as $name) {
    if ( ! is_file($name)) continue ;
    if ( preg_match("%\.(swp|php)$%i", $name)) continue ;
    $isImage = preg_match('%\.(jpe*g|png|gif|heic)$%i', $name) ;
    if ($isImage) {
        printf("%s", $name) ;
        $exif = @exif_read_data($name, null, true) ;
        if (is_array($exif)) {
            if (isset($exif['GPS'])) {
                printf(" ... has GPS data") ;
                }
            else
                printf(" ... does not have GPS data") ;
            }
        printf(" <br/>\n") ;
        }
    }
```

(Note: this is the very script you can run [here](https://web.lovelady.com/stackoverflow-73557696/) to see for yourself.)

Feel free to download the script and the two images [here](https://web.lovelady.com/stackoverflow-73557696/question.zip).  I've supplied them in an effort to hopefully answer any questions I might not have covered in this post.

Comment: If you remove the `@` in front of `exif_read_data()`, you will get a PHP warning when reading the file you say doesn't work: `PHP Notice:  exif_read_data(): Potentially invalid endianess, trying again with different endianness before imminent failure.` Not sure if it's the cause, but it could be that some data is corrupt and that PHP's exif lib can't resolve it, thus not getting all exif data.

Comment: Thanks @M. Ericson , yes, I get this error for a few unrelated images that also return GPS data, so I added the @. These two files are from a DJI Mavic3 drone, which has two builti-in cameras. I get that error also (and no GPS data from exif_read_data()) for any file from the smaller camera, and no error from the Hasselblad.

Comment: There's a [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72682) for this exact issue. It's an old issue (2016), but if you read the comments you can see that people still had the same issue in 2019 and 2020 with newer PHP versions. Maybe check if there are some third-party library that can read the data properly?